# How to print QGraphicsTextItem in MFC application

Tags: qt, mfc, qt4, qt-mfc-migration

I have used QGraphicsTextItem in my MFC applications for text editing, then converted the results to a bitmap to show in the view (screen). But it has issues when printing. For example, if I print to a PDF file, the text is not scalable since it is a bitmap and the file size is also big.

How can I print the QGraphicsTextItem in the MFC printing framework? The ideal solution is that we can hook QPrinter into the MFC printing framework or I can initialize QPrinter with Win32 DC. MFC printing framework has prepared printer and DC for me, so I don't need QPrintDialog to do that task again. **The code may something like this:**

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.paintEngine()->setDC(myHDC); //**Note: this line is imagined by me.
QPainter painter(&printer);
```

Is that possible? Do I have to reimplement my own QPrinter? Scanning QPrinter's source code, I found it very complex. I hope there is an easy way to get my goal. If I have to implement my own QPrinter, what should I need to notice? Can anyone give me some advices?